# Nesting for Year with BRFSS Data in svydesign

Tags: r, survey

I am working to combine multiple years of national BRFSS data into one set and incorporate the appropriate complex survey design with the `survey` package in order to be able to calculate uncertainties. I have seen several examples on how to do this with one year, and know that when doing it for multiple years that I need to nest for `year`, but I'm not quite sure how to include this. Here is the data I am working from reweighted with the variable `finalwt`:

```
> glimpse(df)
Rows: 1,756,594
Columns: 15
$ year        <dbl> 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016~
$ age         <dbl> 43, 59, 80, 70, 18, 65, 74, 76, 43, 56, 75, 61, 57, 58, 70, 62, 65, 52, 37, 80, 36, 34, 80, 66, 72, ~
$ sex         <fct> Male, Female, Female, Male, Male, Female, Female, Female, Female, Male, Female, Female, Male, Female~
$ race        <fct> White, White, White, White, White, White, White, White, White, White, White, White, White, Other, Wh~
$ insured     <fct> Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, ~
$ met_mam     <dbl> NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 1, 0, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, N~
$ met_pap     <dbl> NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 0, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 0, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1, ~
$ met_crc     <dbl> NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1~
$ met_lcs     <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ~
$ psu         <dbl> 2.016e+09, 2.016e+09, 2.016e+09, 2.016e+09, 2.016e+09, 2.016e+09, 2.016e+09, 2.016e+09, 2.016e+09, 2~
$ ststr       <dbl> 11011, 11011, 11011, 11011, 11011, 11011, 11011, 11011, 11011, 11011, 11011, 11011, 11011, 11011, 11~
$ llcpwt      <dbl> 767.8446, 329.6599, 290.7493, 211.0392, 1582.5398, 540.0474, 323.2903, 522.1566, 973.1335, 205.5001,~
$ finalwt1618 <dbl> 395.39989, 169.75764, 149.72072, 108.67418, 814.92545, 278.09623, 166.47765, 268.88341, 501.11298, 1~
$ finalwt1719 <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ~
$ finalwt     <dbl> 203.69399, 87.45225, 77.13005, 55.98453, 419.81655, 143.26390, 85.76254, 138.51783, 258.15309, 54.51~
```

And this is my `svydesign()` code:

```
#build in complex survey design
options(survey.lonely.psu = "adjust")
des <- svydesign(ids= ~1, strata= ~ststr, weights= ~finalwt, nest=T, data = df)
```

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: maybe something like `brfss_design <- svydesign( id = ~ xpsu , strata = ~ interaction( xststr , year ) , data = brfss_df , weight = ~ xllcpwt , nest = TRUE )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to treat the years as extra strata. They are strata, because the number of PSUs sampled each year is fixed in advance. So, as @Anthony says in comments

```
brfss_design <- svydesign( id = ~ psu , strata = ~ interaction( ststr , year ) , data = df , weight = ~ finalwt , nest = TRUE )
```

where `finalwt` needs to be the original weights divided by the number of years, so it adds up to one copy of the US population (rather than as many copies as there are years)